Chern-Simons (K matrix) theory and ${\rm Spin}^{\mathbb C}$ connections
If I understand correctly (e.g. from this paper), an Abelian bosonic Chern-Simons theory defined on $T^2\times \mathbb R$ is specified by a $K$ matrix via e.g. $S \sim \int_M K_{IJ}A^I \wedge dA^J$. The $K$-matrix is the Gram matrix of some lattice, and the lattice needs to be integral. Furthermore, the lattice needs to be even in order for the theory to be a well-defined bosonic theory (for a CS theory to be bosonic, it means that it emerges as an EFT with bosonic degrees of freedom, right?). The anyons are labeled by the discriminant group of the lattice, and the braiding relations and topological spins of the anyons are specified entirely by the inverse matrix $K^{-1}$.
Does anything about the braiding or topological spins of the anyons change when instead considering a spin CS theory? Once we choose a ${\rm Spin}^{\mathbb C}$ structure, it seems that the lattice no longer needs to be even. What concretely does the ${\rm Spin}^{\mathbb C}$ structure change anything about theory? Given a single lattice (i.e. $K$ matrix) but two different ${\rm Spin}^{\mathbb C}$ structures, do we get two truly different things? From Eq. 2.12b of arXiv:hep-th/0505235, it seems like the spin structure would change braiding relations, but I have never seen it explicitly worked out.
(As a related aside, I'd also love any recommendations for references about ${\rm Spin}^{\mathbb C}$ connections; e.g. how they differ from Spin connections, when we should use one or the other, etc.)
